# Find out last number in Regex

Tags: regex

I'm new with regex and I want to solve the following problem. I want to find out the last number in a regex and the next number should allow only plus one.

here is an example:

`123+4` this should works because the last number is 3 and the next number after the + is 4 (3 plus 1)
`123+3` this should not work because the last number is 3 and the next number after the plus is also 3

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: This is not the sort of problem that is properly solved by a regular expression. You should extract your patterns, and then use your programming language to test the truthiness of the last digit/group you captured.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
\d*(?:(?:1\+2)|(?:2\+3)|(?:3\+4)|(?:4\+5)(?:5\+6)|(?:6\+7)|(?:7\+8)|(?:8\+9))
```

[As seen here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gjFg7m/1)

## Explanation:

There's no fancy trick to be used, all you can do is use the regex non-capturing group for every combination of digits as given in the solution. A non-capturing group allows us to combine sequences in parentheses without making them a separate capturing group. It's used like so: `(?:sequence here)`